SwiftUI custom camera
In my application, there are 5 different tabs in the tab bar. One of them is the camera tab. When you click it, the custom camera I made opens. However, when you switch to the camera tab from one of the other tabs, it takes too long to open the camera. How can I solve this?
Tab view
struct ContentView: View {
    @State private var selectedTab: Tab = .Home


    var body: some View {
        VStack(spacing: 0) {
            switch selectedTab {
                case .Camera:
                    PhotoView()
                        .transition(.identity)
                case .Records:
                    Color.gray
                        .transition(.identity)
                case .Home:
                    HomeView()
                        .transition(.identity)
                case .Test:
                    Color.cyan
                        .transition(.identity)
                case .Settings:
                    SettingsView()
                        .transition(.identity)
            }
            
            CustomTabBar(selectedTab: $selectedTab)
        }
    }
}

Camera view and model

struct PhotoView: View {
    @ObservedObject var camera = CameraModel()
    
    var body: some View {
        ZStack {
            GeometryReader { proxy in
                let size = proxy.size
                
                CameraPreview(camera: camera, size: size)
            }
            
            VStack {
                if camera.isTaken {
                    HStack {
                        Spacer()
                        
                        Button {
                            camera.reTake()
                        } label: {
                            Image(systemName: "arrow.triangle.2.circlepath.camera")
                                .foregroundStyle(.black)
                                .padding()
                                .background(.white)
                                .clipShape(Circle())
                                .padding(.trailing, 10)
                                .padding(.top, 10)
                        }
                    }
                }
                
                Spacer()
                
                HStack {
                    if camera.isTaken {
                        Button {
                            if !camera.isSaved {
                                camera.savePic()
                            }
                        } label: {
                            Text(camera.isSaved ? "Saved" : "Save")
                                .foregroundStyle(.black)
                                .fontWeight(.semibold)
                                .padding(.vertical, 10)
                                .padding(.horizontal, 20)
                                .background(.white)
                                .clipShape(Capsule())
                                .padding(.leading)
                                .padding(.bottom, 10)
                        }

                        Spacer()
                        
                    } else {
                        Button {
                            camera.takePic()
                        } label: {
                            ZStack {
                                Circle()
                                    .fill(.white)
                                    .frame(width: 65, height: 65)
                                Circle()
                                    .stroke(.white, lineWidth: 2)
                                    .frame(width: 70, height: 70)
                            }
                            .padding(.bottom, 10)
                        }
                    }
                }
            }
        }
        .onAppear {
            camera.Check()
        }
    }
}

class CameraModel: NSObject, ObservableObject, AVCapturePhotoCaptureDelegate {
    @Published var isTaken = false
    var session = AVCaptureSession()
    var alert = false
    var output = AVCapturePhotoOutput()
    var preview : AVCaptureVideoPreviewLayer!
    @Published var isSaved = false
    var picData = Data(count: 0)

    func Check() {
        switch AVCaptureDevice.authorizationStatus(for: .video) {
            case .authorized:
                setUp()
                return
            case .notDetermined:
                AVCaptureDevice.requestAccess(for: .video) { (status) in
                    if status {
                        self.setUp()
                    }
                }
            case .denied:
                self.alert.toggle()
                return
            default:
                return
        }
    }
    
    func setUp() {
        do {
            self.session.beginConfiguration()
            
            let device = AVCaptureDevice.default(.builtInWideAngleCamera, for: .video, position: .back)
            
            let input = try AVCaptureDeviceInput(device: device!)
            
            if self.session.canAddInput(input) {
                self.session.addInput(input)
            }
            
            if self.session.canAddOutput(self.output) {
                self.session.addOutput(self.output)
            }
            
            self.session.commitConfiguration()
            
        } catch {
            print(error.localizedDescription)
        }
    }
    
    func takePic() {
        DispatchQueue.global(qos: .background).async {

            self.output.capturePhoto(with: AVCapturePhotoSettings(), delegate: self)
            
            DispatchQueue.main.async {
                withAnimation {
                    self.isTaken.toggle()
                }
            }
        }
        
        DispatchQueue.main.asyncAfter(deadline: .now() + 0.3) {
          self.session.stopRunning()
        }
    }
    
    
    func reTake() {
        DispatchQueue.global(qos: .background).async {
            self.session.startRunning()
            
            DispatchQueue.main.async {
                withAnimation {
                    self.isTaken.toggle()
                }
                self.isSaved = false
            }
        }
    }
    
    func photoOutput(_ output: AVCapturePhotoOutput, didFinishProcessingPhoto photo: AVCapturePhoto, error: Error?) {
        if error != nil {
            return
        }
        
        print("pic taken..")
        
        guard let imageData = photo.fileDataRepresentation() else {
            print("Fotoğraf verisi alınamadı.")
            return
        }
        
        self.picData    = imageData
    }
    
    func savePic() {
        print(self.picData)
        let image = UIImage(data: self.picData)!
        
        UIImageWriteToSavedPhotosAlbum(image, nil, nil, nil)
        
        self.isSaved = true
        
        print("saved successfully..")
    }

}

struct CameraPreview: UIViewRepresentable {
    @ObservedObject var camera: CameraModel
    var size: CGSize

    func makeUIView(context: Context) -> UIView {
        let view = UIView()
        
        camera.preview =  AVCaptureVideoPreviewLayer(session: camera.session)
        camera.preview.frame.size = size
        
        camera.preview.videoGravity = .resizeAspectFill
        view.layer.addSublayer(camera.preview)
        
        camera.session.startRunning()
        
        return view
    }
    
    func updateUIView(_ uiView: UIViewType, context: Context) {
        
    }
}



Note, you should be using @StateObject var camera = CameraModel() and
if you use this model in other views, then it is best to declare it in
your ContentView and pass it the the other views so they can use the same model.

This is most likely due to running camera.session.startRunning() on the main thread. You should call it on a background thread and it should free up the UI.
DispatchQueue.global(qos: .userInteractive).async {
    self.camera.session.startRunning()
}

